# Good Dynamics: How can a third party create an IPA consumable by the Good Wrapping server?

Tags: word-wrap, good-dynamics

We are an independent third party software developer. Our software is currently approved by Apple, and available for download from AppStore. Now we have a potential customer who has Good Dynamics setup (http://www.good.com) (with Good Wrapper, Control, Proxy servers etc.), and we're trying to figure out how our IPA can be made consumable with their Good Wrapper server. Reading the Good Dynamics' Guide to Application Wrapping, it's a little confusing. It states that we "need a ready-to-wrap iOS app (.ipa) build for enterprise or ad hoc distribution. Ready-to-wrap means a working iOS app with a valid signing certificate.".

There are two possible interpretations of this description:
1) We (the independent third party software developer) create a certificate for this potential customer, create an ad hoc provisioning profile with this certificate, create an IPA, and give them this certificate and this IPA. They can feed these to their Good Wrapper server, which will wrap the application.

2) They (the potential customer with a Good Dynamics setup) need to have an Enterprise distribution account (to enable them to distribute applications within their enterprise employees). They need to have a certificate and provisioning profile for this enterprise distribution account. They will provide us with this certificate and profile, and we will compile and create an IPA with this provisioning profile. This IPA will then be handed over to them, and can be fed to their Good Wrapper server.

Which one of the above flows is correct?

Thanks & regards,

Answer (score 1):

The second flow is the correct one. Application wrapping is mostly intended for in-house developers. Just be aware that your particular scenario, where the customer provides you with their certificate, might not be Apple approved.